# unable to install newer opam package on travis ci image

Tags: ocaml, travis-ci, opam

I am using travis-ci to automate unit testing for my ocaml project. I am unable to complete my build so I am testing my build locally with the same docker travis-ci [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/travisci/ci-sardonyx/tags). One of the opam packages `ounit2` is not in the `opam` installed in this image. But when I compile my test suit the error message is

```
ocamlfind: Package `ounit2' not found
Command exited with code 2.
```

I am only able to install `ounit`, which is in opam, but not `ounit2`. What should I do?

```
language: generic

os: linux
env:
  - OCAML_VERSION=4.07.0

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - opam


# Install the specified version of OCaml
before_install:
- opam init --auto-setup --comp="$OCAML_VERSION"

# Install the required dependencies
install:
  - opam install --yes ocamlfind
  - opam install --yes ocamlbuild
  - opam install --yes oUnit
  - opam install --yes menhir

# Set the appropriate environment variables
before_script:
  - eval $(opam config env)

# Build and run the test suite
script:
  - make
  - make test
```